# I need to get sentences with some specifications from some text files and then store them into database

Tags: php, text

I have text that consist of some sentences. I have to parse the sentences that separated by dot and count words in every sentence. The sentences that contain more than 5 words will be inserted into database. here's my code :

```
<?php

require_once 'conf/conf.php';// connect to database

function saveContent ($text) {
  //I have to get every sentence without lose the dot
  $text1 = str_replace('.', ".dot", $text);
  $text2 = explode ('dot',$text1); 

  //Text that contain ' cannot be inserted to database, so i need to remove it 
  $text3 = str_replace("'", "", $text2); 

  //Selecting the sentence that only consist of more than words
  for ($i=0;$i<count($text3);$i++){
    if(count(explode(" ", $text3[$i]))>5){
      $save = $text3[$i];

      $q0 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbdocument VALUES('','$files','".$save."','','','') ");
    }
  }
}

$text= "I have some text files in my folder. I get them from extraction process of pdf journals files into txt files. here's my code";
$a = saveContent($text);

?>
```

The result is only 1 sentence (the first sentence) that can be inserted in database.
I need your help, thank you so much : )

Comment: You _can_ insert `'` into your database if properly escaped.  `$text2 = mysql_real_escape_string($text2);`

Comment: And don't use `mysql_*`, please switch to PDO or `mysqli`

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string`, because `mysql_escape_string` wasn't real enough :D

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to improve this (and to make it work correctly).

Rather than replace `.` with `.dot`, you can simply explode on the `.` and remember to replace it later.  However, what if your sentence is something like *Mr. Smith went to Washington.*?  You can't differentiate those periods with much reliability.

The variable `$files` in your `INSERT` is not defined in scope of this function.  We don't know where it comes from or what you expect it to contain, but here, it will be NULL.

```
function saveContent ($text) {
  // Just explode on the . and replace it later...
  $sentences = explode(".", $text);

  // Don't remove single quotes. They'll be properly escaped later...

  // Rather than an incremental loop, use a proper foreach loop:
  foreach ($sentences as $sentence) {
    // Using preg_split() instead of explode() in case there are multiple spaces in sequence
    if (count(preg_split('/\s+/', $sentence)) > 5) {
      // Escape and insert
      // And add the . back onto it
      $save = mysql_real_escape_string($sentence) . ".";

      // $files is not defined in scope of this function!
      $q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbdocument VALUES('', '$files', '$sentence', '', '', '')");
      // Don't forget to check for errors.
      if (!$q) {
        echo mysql_error();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the long run, consider moving away from the `mysql_*()` functions and begin learning an API which supports prepared statements such as PDO or MySQLi.  The old `mysql_*()` functions are soon to be deprecated and lack the security offered by prepared statements.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've tried your code, but I get an error. The instruction at "0x005cc0" referenced memory at "0x00000010". The memory could not be "read". what's wrong ?

Comment: @puresmile If you are getting errors about memory addresses, they are more likely related to a problem with your MySQL installation or an actual fault with your computer's RAM memory.  PHP code won't generate an error like that.